# Transparency discrepancy between webgl and 2d canvases

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl

I have a png, which I load using 2d `canvas`, and as a webgl texture. The png has some transparent parts, which are rendered black in webgl, and white in the 2d `canvas`. (Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PErKw/) for a live demo. In Chrome, you need to run with the flag `--disable-web-security` to bypass cross-origin restrictions.)

Is there a way to set the transparency color for webgl textures? What about for 2d canvases?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PErKw/1/ uses data uri's so you wouldn't have to run with some security flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading the texture as RGB in `createTexture` and therefore throwing away the alpha channel. Change it to RGBA as in

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
```

And they'll look the same.

Answer (score 0):

In order for canvas to understand your png transparency, you'll need to save it in 24-bit.

> Because 24-bit PNG images include a full 8-bit alpha channel.

[Full reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images)

Comment: Hum. Why would 2d-canvas and 3d-canvas the same image differently?

Comment: Because they render in a different way. They're not the same.